# How to return value of json string in mysql

Tags: mysql, json

Let's say that we have the following table 'articles':

```
id_article | article_title
     1     | {"ar":"Arabic value", "en":"English value", "tr":"Turkish value"}
     2     | {"ar":"Arabic value", "en":"English value", "tr":"Turkish value"}
     3     | {"ar":"Arabic value", "en":"English value", "tr":"Turkish value"}
     4     | {"ar":"Arabic value", "en":"English value", "tr":"Turkish value"}
     5     | {"ar":"Arabic value", "en":"English value", "tr":"Turkish value"}
     6     | {"ar":"Arabic value", "en":"English value", "tr":"Turkish value"}
     7     | {"ar":"Arabic value", "en":"English value", "tr":"Turkish value"}
```

And let's say that we also have the following table 'seen':

```
id_seen | id_item_seen
   1    |      3
   2    |      5
   3    |      5
   4    |      3
   5    |      3
   6    |      3
   7    |      3
   8    |      2
   9    |      2
   10   |      4
   11   |      1
   12   |      7
   13   |      7
```

I've executed the following SQL query:

```
select articles.id_article, articles.id_article, count(*) as seens from seen
inner join articles on articles.id_article = seen.id_item_seen
group by articles.id_article
order by seens desc
```

This will return the following result:

```
id_article | article_title                                                     | seens
     1     | {"ar":"Arabic value", "en":"English value", "tr":"Turkish value"} |   1
     2     | {"ar":"Arabic value", "en":"English value", "tr":"Turkish value"} |   2
     3     | {"ar":"Arabic value", "en":"English value", "tr":"Turkish value"} |   5
     4     | {"ar":"Arabic value", "en":"English value", "tr":"Turkish value"} |   1
     5     | {"ar":"Arabic value", "en":"English value", "tr":"Turkish value"} |   2
     6     | {"ar":"Arabic value", "en":"English value", "tr":"Turkish value"} |   0
     7     | {"ar":"Arabic value", "en":"English value", "tr":"Turkish value"} |   2
```

This is ok, but I want to return not all of the stored JSON {}, but just a specified value of desired key (for example: "ar") as the following:

```
     1     | Arabic value |   1
     2     | Arabic value |   2
     3     | Arabic value |   5
     4     | Arabic value |   1
     5     | Arabic value |   2
     6     | Arabic value |   0
     7     | Arabic value |   2
```

I know we could do this with PHP using json_decode() function, but How could we achieve this with SQL query?

Comment: Your mysql version?

Comment: my MySQL version is 5.6.35

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SBTRING_INDEX in mysql < 5.7.Replace that json with your column name.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('{"ar":"Arabic value", "en":"English value", "tr":"Turkish value"}','ar":"',-1),'"',1)
```

[See it working.](http://rextester.com/HHQD35391)

Comment: Hola! That's what I'm looking for! Very THANK YOU! <3

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MySQL 5.7 and the column is of JSON type (as it should be) you can retrieve it with

```
select articles.id_article, articles.article_title->'$.ar', count(*) as seens from seen
inner join articles on articles.id_article = seen.id_item_seen
group by articles.id_article
order by seens desc
```

See the [documentation of the JSON type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html).

If you have an older version of MySQL then it would be better to handle the extraction outside the server to make sure it's handled properly.

Comment: OOOOOOHHH :-( my mysql version is 5.6.35
I see that it's in-executable query.

However, thank you :-)